# Search model based on minimum data of a column at rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I'd like to search a model based on minimum data of a column at ruby on rails.
In particular, I want to search the answer data which score is highest. 
I've been implementing as following now, but it's not simple because it uses array.
Could you tell the method not using array?

```
#Answer_model
id:Int
name:string
point:Int

#/app/model/answer.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :highest,-> {
    order("point ASC")
  }
end

#/app/controllers/answer_controllers.rb
@user = Answer.highest[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`highest` returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` for which you can't call `[]` on. Instead select the first element using `first`, like this:

```
@user = Answer.highest.first
```

Comment: Can I use  `scope :lowest,-> {
    order("point DESC")
  }` to get the lowest?